# C# Sql Server setting datasource = localhost

Tags: c#

When I change my sql server Connection to:

```
SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog = Semester 2 Project SD; Integrated Security=SSPI");
```

It gives me an error saying that it cant find the server or can't connect to it.

Is my string/ sql connection completely wrong or is there anything i need to change in SQL server, or both?

When I use  `server = BACON1-PC\\SQLEXPRESS` it works completely fine though.

Comment: Why not try "localhost\SQLEXPRESS" then?  I remember also ".\SQLEXPRESS" working.

Comment: You need to use `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`, since that is the instance name of your SQL server.

Comment: Thanks, it works, however i had to make one slight change before i got it working. Adding an extra \  eg "localhost\\SQLEXPRESS"